# Django User model throws duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_user_username_key" on user creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I am testing my user model to see if it's signal works correctly however, I am getting an error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
```

Currently my test is:

```
class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    
    obj1 = None
    obj2 = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.obj1 = User.objects.create(first_name="james", last_name="adams", email="jamesadams@gmail.com")
        self.obj2 = User.objects.create(first_name="amy", last_name="", email="12amy_123jackson@hotmail.com")
```

And my signals file is:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="set_username_of_user")
def set_username(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Every time a user is saved, ensures that user has a certain username
    This method avoids users having username field set to null
    """
    if not instance.username:
        email = instance.email
        email_without_domain = email[:email.find("@")].replace("-","_").lower().strip()[:20].replace(' ','')
        username = create_username(email_without_domain)
        print(username)
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            while User.objects.filter(username=username):
                username = create_username(email_without_domain)
            instance.username = username
            instance.save()
```

I can confirm that the signal is being called however, it still throws that error. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: It looks like an empty string may be getting passed from the error.

Comment: What is `create_username`? Does it actually return something?